# Using a php Variable to setStartDate and setEndDate for google analytics API V4

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to pull some simple metrics from the google analytics API. When setting the dates manually it returns the result as expected. When i try to set the date using a variable it does not work. the below code works

```
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate("2017-12-01");
$dateRange->setEndDate("2017-12-31");
```

When i try to do the same thing but using a variable like shown it does not. The url parameters used are ?startDate=2017-12-01&endDate=2017-12-31

```
$tstartDate=filter_var($_GET["startDate"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$tendDate=filter_var($_GET["endDate"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate("$tstartDate");
$dateRange->setEndDate("$tendDate");
```

The error code being returned by google is "Both dateRange.startDate and dateRange.endDate should be specified." Does anyone know why it is failing when done using a variable?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are parsing a string containing your variable names to the Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange(). Try parsing it as a variable, like I have below.

```
$tstartDate=filter_var($_GET["startDate"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$tendDate=filter_var($_GET["endDate"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate($tstartDate);
$dateRange->setEndDate($tendDate);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking but I had already tried this and it still gives the same error.

Comment: Have you tried var_dumping the object to the screen or logs so that we can see what the object contains? 

Also if you could show me the exception being thrown that would be great!

Comment: string(10) "2017-12-01" string(10) "2017-12-31"

Comment: [09-Mar-2018 11:05:02 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Both dateRange.startDate and dateRange.endDate should be specified.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Both dateRange.startDate and dateRange.endDate should be specified.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
' in /home/yahireco/public_html/prs/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118

Comment: It looks like you object is being created ok using the variables its being parsed, are you parsing your DateRange object to the Google Service Request object as show in this documentation.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php

Comment: No I am using the example for a web application found here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php

Comment: Ok it seems similar, have you implemented a method which is similar to the  
    function getReport($analytics) {}
As that is building the URL which is being parsed to GA. From the exception you posted I can see that the dates inputted aren't reaching the Google Analytic API

Comment: Yes this is correct but the problem is why. The variable $startDate is a value of 2017-12-01 does not work when it is exactly the same as putting in $dateRange->setStartDate("2017-12-01"); i can not see what the difference is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was doing the GET for the URL parameters outside of the getReport Function...

```
function getReport($analytics){


$VIEW_ID = "xxxxxx";

// Create the DateRange object.

$tstartDate=filter_var($_GET["startDate"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$tendDate=filter_var($_GET["endDate"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate($tstartDate);
$dateRange->setEndDate($tendDate);

// Create the Metrics object.
$sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
$sessions->setAlias("sessions");

// Create the ReportRequest object.
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
$request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

$body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
$body->setReportRequests(array( $request));
return $analytics->reports->batchGet($body);}
```

This now works as desired!